# Duplicate file finder that focuses on folders

Tags: gratis, file-management, duplicate-files

I've tried many duplicate finder programs, but they tend to focus on the files by listing all the files on top of one another with the various locations. What I want is to focus on the folders.

After searching my computer with a duplicate file programme, I then want the option to delete all the files FROM A SELECTED FOLDER.

Is there any free programs that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found one of sorts: [Duplicate Cleaner](https://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/duplicatecleaner.html).  It has a paid version as well as a free version with limited functionality.

When you have done a search, within the results there is a column "path" that is **sortable**.

This groups all the duplicates by location; which makes it easy to select, then delete, all the duplicates within one folder.

Answer (score 2):

Also [dupeGuru](https://github.com/arsenetar/dupeguru) would definitely be
a good open source alternative for Linux/macOS/WindowsMAC.

Similarly to other suggested alternatives here, a click on the "folder" (on MAC) / "directory" (on Linux) column shall let you sort your duplicates by folder. It will then be easy for you to select all duplicates from the same folder and delete them.

On MAC:

[image: https://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru/scr/mac_main.png]

On Linux:

[image: screenshot of dupeguru on Linux]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows for this then [DoubleKiller](https://www.bigbangenterprises.de/en/doublekiller/) might be good for this. A free version exists and, just like Duplicate Cleaner that was suggested in the other answer, DoubleKiller let's you sort the duplicates list result by path so to see all duplicates contained in the same folder to be shown close together and can be. (NOTE: you can also sort found duplicates by file name, or size, the paid pro version let's you change list sort mode as you like switching from the one to another, whereas the free version let's you choose sorting method just ONE time after the results are shown, thus you're compelled to re-run the process to change sort mode after.) You can also right click on a duplicate found file to open its parent directory if you need to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the open source application [czkawka](https://qarmin.github.io/czkawka/) which runs on Linux / macOS / Windows. It differs from the already mentioned applications, in the way that you can make a "custom selection" of the duplicates, which includes the possibility to filter by name, path or regex path + name:

[image: Screenshot of the application]